# Lower-bound smallest eigenvalue of covariance matrix of $y = f(Ax)$, for $x$ uniform on unit-sphere

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, st.statistics, geometric-probability, lower-bounds

Let $A=(a_1,\ldots,a_)$ be a fixed $k \times d$ matrix (with $d$ large), and $x$ be a random vector uniformly distributed on the unit-sphere in $\mathbb R^d$. Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a positively-homogeneous $1$-Lipschitz continuous function, and let $C \in \mathbb R^{k \times k}$ be the covariance matrix of random vector $y:=f(Ax) := (f(a_1^\top x),\ldots,f(a_k^\top x)) \in \mathbb R^k$.

> **Question.** Is it possible to give **lower-bounds** on the smallest eigenvalue of $C$ which only depend on spectral properties of $A$ ?

**N.B.:** I'm particularly interested in the cases *(i)* $f(t):=\max(t,0)$, and *(ii)* $f(t) = |t|$.

### Example

Consider the the case where $f(t) := t$, so that $C = cov(Wx) = Wcov(x)W^\top = (1/d)WW^\top$. Thus, $\lambda_{\min}(C) = (1/d)\lambda_{\min}(WW^\top)$.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.05419 could be useful. In particular check Table 1 there which gives $E[f(a^Tx) f(b^Tx)]$ for various example including max(0,t) and |t|. Some results there should also give you some asymptotic distributions of the eigenvalues. Various works with similar results in the last few years are cited there or cite this work.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've solved my problem since then, and should writeup and answer asap. Indeed, in certain cases (when $f$ is positive homogeneous), C is a dot-product kernel and there are lots of papers (pioneered by El Karoui's https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-38/issue-1/The-spectrum-of-kernel-random-matrices/10.1214/08-AOS648.full)  on the eigenvalues of such random matrices.